# Which methods can be used to return valid and invalid XML data from a file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, xquery

I have the following data that is supposed to be XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>A new product</description>
    <price>123.45</price>
</Product>

<Product>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>A new product</description>
    <price>123.45</price>
</Product>

<ProductTTTTT>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>A new product</description>
    <price>123.45</price>
</Product>

<Product>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>A new product</description>
    <price>123.45</price>
</ProductAAAAAA>
```

So, basically I have multiple root elements (`product`)...

The point is that I'm trying to transform this data into 2 XML documents, 1 for valid nodes and other for invalid nodes.

Valid node:

```
<Product>
   ...
</Product>
```

Invalid nodes: `<ProductTTTTT>...</Product>` and `<Product>...</ProductAAAAAA>`

Then I am thinking how I can achieve this using JAVA (not web).

- If I am not wrong, validating it with a XSD will invalidate the whole file, so not an option.
- Using default JAXB parser (unmarshaller) will lead to item above since internally it creates a XSD of my entity.
- Using XPath just (from what I know) will just return the whole file, I did not find a way to get something like GET !VALID (It is just to explain...)
- Using XQuery (maybe?).. by the way, how to use XQuery with JAXB?
- XSL(T) will lead to same thing on XPath, since it uses XPath to select the content.

So... which method can I use to achieve the objective? (And if possible, provide links or code please)

Comment: By definition, an XML file can only have a single [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).

Comment: As @MickMnemonic said, sanitizing your XML to have only one root element will fix some(all?) of your problems.

Comment: I understand and agree with both of you, but unfortunately I do not have access to the system that sends this xml format. Any other option?

Comment: Why do you refer to it as an XML format, when you've been told that it isn't?

Comment: Just a way to refer to this 'thing'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contains lines with start and end tags who's name begins with "Product", you could:

- use a file scanner to split this document into individual pieces whenever a line starts with `<Product` or `</Product`
- attempt to parse the extracted text as XML using an XML API.

  - If it succeeds, add that object to a list of "good" well-formed XML documents

    - then perform any additional schema validation or validity checks
  - If it throws a parse error, catch it, and add that snippet of text to the list of "bad" items that need to be cleaned up or otherwise handled

An example to get you started:

```
package com.stackoverflow.questions.52012383;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileSplitter {

    public static void parseFile(File file, String elementName) 
      throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

        List<Document> good = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> bad = new ArrayList<>();

        String start-tag = "<" + elementName;
        String end-tag = "</" + elementName;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        boolean append = false;

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();

                if (line.startsWith(startTag)) {
                    append = true; //start accumulating content
                } else if (line.startsWith(endTag)) {
                    append = false;
                    buffer.append(line); 
                    //instead of the line above, you could hard-code the ending tag to compensate for bad data:
                    // buffer.append(endTag + ">");

                    try { // to parse as XML
                        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(buffer.toString())));
                        good.add(document); // parsed successfully, add it to the good list

                        buffer.setLength(0); //reset the buffer to start a new XML doc

                    } catch (SAXException ex) {
                        bad.add(buffer.toString()); // something is wrong, not well-formed XML
                    }
                }

                if (append) { // accumulate content
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Good items: " + good.size() + " Bad items: " + bad.size());
            //do stuff with the good/bad results...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
      throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        File file = new File("/tmp/test.xml");
        parseFile(file, "Product");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Mads Hansen, thanks for you time helping me here...

With your (and others) answers, I could understand that has no right way to do it since it's not a xml. Anyway, I was thinking something like you wrote. The only part that needs attention is that you are only validating <Product, this way something like <ProductAAAA will not get handled.

Comment: You could also adapt that strategy to normalize those closing elements, so if it starts with `</Product` but isn't equal to `</Product>`, then replace that line with `</Product>` and try to parse (or do that in the catch for parse exceptions). I wasn't sure if you wanted to "fix it" or just find the valid items. Feel free to adapt, but hopefully that was enough to get you started.

Comment: Be sure that not only you but @Michael Kay helped me, even with that aggressiveness answers XD I understood his intentions.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you're confusing valid and well-formed. You say you want to find invalid elements, but your examples aren't just invalid, they are ill-formed. That means that no XML parser is going to do anything with them other than throwing an error message at you. You can't use JAXB or XPath, or XQuery, or XSLT, or anything to process something that isn't XML.

You say "unfortunately I do not have access to the system that sends this xml format". I'm not sure why you call it an XML format: it isn't. I also don't understand why you (and many others on StackOverflow) are prepared to spend your time digging in garbage like this rather than telling the sender to get their act together. If you were served a salad with maggots in it, would you try to pick them out, or would you send it back for replacement? You should adopt a zero-tolerance approach to bad data; that's the only way senders will learn to improve the quality.

Comment: I fully understand and agree with you (I already tried it before coming here), they should send good data for me but unfortunately I don't have this choice. So let's be real, or I do what my boss asks or get fired, simple like this. It's kind frustrating...
Anyway, sorry dude but I can't accept this as an answer to the question.

Comment: Your answer tells about a very interesting and important point of view that every developer should do, so I marked it as useful. Thanks!

Comment: Engineers who do what their boss (or client) asks without questioning it end up being responsible for disasters like Grenfell.